# Jquery event lister acting differently under iOS6 vs iOS5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ios

I've been studying the code behind [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/FlipboardPageLayout/) for a few days and I've noticed that while it works as expected on iOS5, the boxes don't expand under iOS6 when clicked. I've tried a few different things, and the only way I can find to expand the boxes in iOS6 is to add an `<a href="#">something</a>` link to the box and click on it from the full page view. This expands the box, but just tapping in the whitespace, which should expand it, does nothing at all. What might be the cause of this?

Comment: I see its broken on iOS 6 but can't see the code. Might guess that the way the element heights are not being set correctly.

Comment: The code is at http://tympanus.net/Development/FlipboardPageLayout/FlipboardPageLayout.zip .